# angular 5 dynamic navbar with materializecss

Tags: angular, angular5

my `categories` have this data ... im tying to show related subcategory when mouse hover on category name on navbar

```
 categories =  [ { "title": "webdevelop", "sub": [ "php", "html" ] }, { "title": "androidDevelop", "sub": [ "python" ] } ]
```

i did somthing like this but if i hover on category name all subcategory will show i tried to use dynamic name for `data-activates` but angular will not accept how can i solve this issue?

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper grey darken-3">
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down second-nav">
      <li *ngFor="let cat of categories">
        <a>
          <span (mouseover)="hover($event)" class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates=""
                data-beloworigin="true">{{ cat.title }}
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Dropdown -->
<ul *ngFor="let cat of categories" id="" class="dropdown-content collection">
  <li class="collection-item avatar" *ngFor="let sc of cat.sub">
      <span>
        {{ sc }}
      </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

it is hover function :

```
 hover() {
    $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
        inDuration: 300,
        outDuration: 225,
        hover: true, // Activate on hover
        belowOrigin: true, // Displays dropdown below the button
        alignment: 'right' // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange to see jQuery code inside angular. Is there any way to avoid jQuery in your project? 
Currently your `hover()` simply attaches another hover listener to the navbar, which is wrong. If you want to keep jQuery - try to attach all those listeners  in `ngAfterViewInit()`.
But here is how I'd make it without jQuery usage.

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper grey darken-3">
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down second-nav">
      <li *ngFor="let cat of categories">
        <a>
          <span (mouseover)="hover($event, cat)" (mouseleave)="unhover($event)" class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates=""
                data-beloworigin="true">{{ cat.title }}
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Dropdown -->
<div *ngIf="hoveredCategory">
<ul id="hoveredCategory" class="dropdown-content collection">
  <li class="collection-item avatar" *ngFor="let sc of hoveredCategory.sub">
      <span>
        {{ sc }}
      </span>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

then update hover method and component class

```
class ... {
  hoveredCategory: any;
  ...

  hover(event, category) {
    this.hoveredCategory = category;
  }
  unhover(event) {
    this.hoveredCategory = null;
  }
```

this code will display subcategories of hovered category, you just need to take care of stylization of your dropdown.